# Set user home folder to local path doesn't seem to actually set the profile location for domain or local users

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I have created a folder `D:\Users` with the same permissions as the default `C:\Users` and enabled the "Set user home folder." I have verified that the GPO is applied to the computer on which I am testing.

[image]
After logging in for the first time with a domain or local user, a folder does get automatically created in a format of `DOMAIN.user` but the folder contents are empty and it looks like Windows is using a folder under `C:\Users` for all the contents that would typically be in a user profile folder like Documents, etc.

What am I missing? Is it likely a permissions issue with `D:\Users` or am I misunderstanding what "Set user home folder" does?

Edit: Depending on the permissions, I also get "We can't sign in to your account" on login (and it uses a temporary profile) at times. Interestingly this happens *even when a folder does get created for the user.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're misunderstanding what "Set user home folder" does. It does not redirect the user profile nor does it redirect the default user profile folders (Documents, Downloads, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In this context, by "home directory" or "home folder" Windows just means a location, usually on the network, where users can choose to put their files; I believe the terminology dates all the way back to DOS, before there was such a thing as a user profile or a Documents folder.  This causes a certain amount of confusion.

To the best of my knowledge, all the home folder setting actually does is to create the folder if it doesn't already exist, optionally map a drive letter, and set some environment variables to point to it.  Most applications will ignore the environment variables; a few may assume that they point to your user profile and may or may not behave sensibly when they do not.

There is a separate group policy setting (User Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Folder Redirection) that allows you to redirect the Documents and various other user folders; as far as I am aware, [there is no supported way,](https://www.zdnet.com/article/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive/) using group policy or otherwise, to relocate the user profile itself.